# MomentJS: explanation about manipulation date with different locale. Is it a bug?

Tags: javascript, date, momentjs

I want to get first day of the first week of the year.

So:

```
import moment from 'moment';  

const jan = moment([2017, 0]);
const firstDayWeekYear = jan.clone().week(1).day(1);
console.log("jan", jan.format('DD/MMM/YYYY')); // jan 01/Jan/2017
console.log("firstDayWeekYear", firstDayWeekYear.format('DD/MMM/YYYY')); // firstDayWeekYear 02/Jan/2017  (correct)
```

but if I use the italian locale, I get this

```
import moment from 'moment';
import 'moment/locale/it';

const jan = moment([2017, 0]);
const firstDayWeekYear = jan.clone().week(1).day(1);
console.log("jan", jan.format('DD/MMM/YYYY')); // 01/gen/2017
console.log("firstDayWeekYear", firstDayWeekYear.format('DD/MMM/YYYY')); // firstDayWeekYear 11/gen/2016  (why 2016?)
```

in 2018 it works correctly again

```
 const jan = moment([2018, 0]);
    const firstDayWeekYear = jan.clone().week(1).day(1);
    console.log("jan", jan.format('DD/MMM/YYYY')); // 01/gen/2018
    console.log("firstDayWeekYear", firstDayWeekYear.format('DD/MMM/YYYY')); // firstDayWeekYear 01/gen/2018  (correct)
```

...but in 2021...

```
const jan = moment([2021, 0]);
const firstDayWeekYear = jan.clone().week(1).day(1);
console.log("jan", jan.format('DD/MMM/YYYY')); // 01/gen/2021
console.log("firstDayWeekYear", firstDayWeekYear.format('DD/MMM/YYYY')); // firstDayWeekYear 30/dic/2019  (why 2019?)
```

Can someone explane to me why in the year after leap year that code doesn't work? Is it a bug?

Edit 1:
moment.utc() creates the same wrong date

Edit 2: 
`const firstDayWeekYear = jan.clone().isoWeek(1).day(1);`  creates always 11/gen/2016

Comment: Try setting time with UTC (e.g. `moment.utc([2017, 0])`)

Comment: @DominicTobias I get always the same wrong date

Comment: The second part of your question (why `moment([2021, 0]).week(1).day(1).format('DD/MMM/YYYY')` outputs `30/dic/2019` for italian locale) is answered in the [`week`](http://momentjs.com/docs/#/get-set/week/) docs. What is really strange for me is why `moment([2017, 0]).week(1).day(1).format('DD/MMM/YYYY')` ouputs `11/gen/2016` for italian locale.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Code for the following is below.

According to [*Savvy time*](https://savvytime.com/week-number/italy/2017), Italy uses the ISO 8601 scheme for numbering days and weeks of the year. So for Italians, the first week of 2017 started on Monday 2 January 2017. The expression:

```
moment([2017, 0]);
```

creates a Date for Sun 1 Jan 2017, which (in the ISO scheme) is the last day of the last week of 2016. Then:

```
.week(1)
```

will set the date to same day of the week (i.e. the last) in the first week of 2016, so Sun 10 Jan 2016. Then:

```
.day(1)
```

should set it to the first day of that week, which is Mon 4 Jan 2016. So if you are getting 1 gennaio (January) 2017, something is going wrong.

In 2018, Mon 1 Jan is also the ISO first day of the ISO first week of 2018.

In 2021, 1 Jan is a Friday, so is again in the last week of the previous year, 2020.

```
.week(1)
```

should go to Fri 3 Jan 2020 (i.e. Friday in the first week of 2020), then

```
.day(1)
```

will shift it to the first day of that week, i.e. Monday, 30 December 2019 (which is actually the first Monday in the first week of 2020).

QED.

The following just uses ISO week and day numbers as an alternative to locale.

```js
var f = 'ddd D MMM YYYY';
var d = moment([2017,0]);
console.log(d.format(f)); // Sun 1 Jan 2017

d.isoWeek(1);
console.log(d.format(f)); // Sun 10 Jan 2017

d.isoWeekday(1);
console.log(d.format(f)); // Mon 4 Jan 2017

var e = moment([2021,0]);
console.log(e.format(f)); // Fri 1 Jan 2021

e.isoWeek(1);
console.log(e.format(f)); // Fri 3 Jan 2020

e.isoWeekday(1);
console.log(e.format(f)); // Mon 30 Dec 2019
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/moment.js/2.18.1/moment.min.js"></script>
```

PS
I think the idea of using a language code to define a locale is misguided. The authors of moment.js could have used the IANA tz database locales (which are based on geographical areas, i.e. actual locales), but instead have followed ECMA 402 in using a language. But languages don't have locales, many (e.g. Spanish, Chinese) are spoken all over the world. The rules for things like the first week of the year and first day of the week tend to be defined by bureaucracies, not languages. A Chinese speaker in in Italy would likely want to use the Italian (locality) schemes for week numbering, not the Chinese ones, so the locality for things like formats and timezone should be based on localities as used by the IANA tz database. The language to use should be an entirely separate parameter.

Comment: good explanation. Indeed, I imported the italian file just to translate name of month and week